# find and replase keyword with link but ignor div content

Tags: php

I wrote a function To find the keyword and convert it to a link Below is the whole function:

```
function Linkkeywords($linksArray, $content){
    $links = $linksArray;
    $links_keys = array_keys($links);
    $linked = array();
    $existingLinks = array();
    foreach ($links_keys as $word ){
        if(!in_array($word, $existingLinks)){
            $existingLinks[] = $word;
            $linked[] = '<a href="'.$links[$word].'">'.$word.'</a>';
        }
    }
    foreach($existingLinks as  $key => $word){
        $c =   preg_replace('|(?!<[^<>]*?)(?<![?./&])\b('.$word.')\b(?!:)(?![^<>]*?>)|iu', $linked[$key], $content,1);
    }
    return $c;
}//End Function Linkkeywords

$linksArray = Array ( 'hello' => 'http://hello.com' );

$content = '
 <div class="alert alert-post-summary">hello world</div>

  hello world
';
echo Linkkeywords($linksArray, $content);
```

The output of this function is as follows:

```
 <div class="alert alert-post-summary"><a href="http://hello.com">hello</a> world</div>

  hello world
```

I want to ignore the content text of the `<div class="alert alert-post-summary">`

i like, the output of the function is as follows:

```
 <div class="alert alert-post-summary">hello world</div>

  <a href="http://hello.com">hello</a> world
```

Comment: Are you specifically required to do this in PHP? It really seems as though JavaScript would be much better suited to this. I say this because `$content` is hard-coded at the moment -- wouldn't it be easier just to actually output the link directly in the HTML itself?

Comment: no i can use javascript , Do you have a function like this with javascript?

Comment: In fact, I want to turn specific keywords into specific links,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your keyword is not in a HTML element, the simplest solution is to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse your string.

A DOMDocument instance can be created as follows : `$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);`

You can then iterate through the Document children : 
`

```
foreach ($document->childNodes() as $child) {
 if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) 
  $child->textContent = str_replace($word, $link, $child->textContent);
}
```

`

And finally retrieve the textContent of the DOMDocument to have your string.
This will replace the keyword in every direct text child nodes of your html string.

Comment: No, I do not want to strip the HTML element around from keywords, I want to add URLs to keywords in string but Except for sentences inside div with class="alert alert-post-summary"

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, I change my answer

Comment: Again my question is not that you answered, Please one time read the my question carefully

Comment: This code replace the keyword with the corresponding link ignoring the text of HTML element like you asked